# Creating an agenda like kendoui scheduler using fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, fullcalendar

In KendoUI scheduler you can switch to "agenda"-view, showing all events as a list: See http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/index.html and click the "agenda"-button.

Is it possible to do the same using fullcalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)? As far as I can tell, it is not possible to create a custom view.

thanks

Thomas

Comment: The closest is basic day/week view. But the agenda view in the link, I think is definitely worth requesting http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/wiki/Request-a-Feature/

Answer (score 3):

Some fullCalendar resource view forks:

- http://www.ikelin.com/jquery-fullcalendar-resource-day-view/
- http://ikelin.github.io/fullcalendar/
- http://seankenny.me/blog/2013/08/14/fullcalendar-with-a-resource-day-view/
- http://embed.plnkr.co/cX9dH8eTjKaddJ0Gpw21/preview